# How to make this asynchronous method invocation working?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, pipeline

I was trying to develop a method pipeline using asynchronous method invocation. The logic for the pipeline is as follows

1. There are n data in a collection that have to be fed into m number of methods in a pipeline
2. Enumerate a collection of T
3. Feed the first element to the first method
4. Get the output, feed it to the second method asynchronously
5. At the same time, feed the second element of the collection to the first method
6. After completion of the first method, fed the result to the second method (if the second method is still running, put the result into its queue and start executing the third element at first method)
7. When second method finishes executing take the first element from the queue and execute and so on (every method should run asynchronously, no one should wait for the next to finish)
8. At the mth method, after executing the data, store the result to a list
9. After completing nth element at the mth method return the list of the results (n number of results) to the very first level.

I came up with a code as follows, but it did not work as intended, the result never gets returned and moreover it is not executing in the order as it should be.

```
static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            var result = list.ForEachPipeline(Add, Square, Add, Square);
            foreach (var element in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int Add(int j)
        {
            return j + 1;
        }

        private static int Square(int j)
        {
            return j * j;
        }

        internal static void AddNotify<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} to the list", item);
            list.Add(item);
        }    
    }

    internal class Function<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, T> _func;

        private readonly List<T> _result = new List<T>();
        private readonly Queue<T> DataQueue = new Queue<T>();
        private bool _isBusy;
        static readonly object Sync = new object();
        readonly ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        internal Function(Func<T, T> func)
        {
            _func = func;
        }

        internal Function<T> Next { get; set; }
        internal Function<T> Start { get; set; }
        internal int Count;

        internal IEnumerable<T> Execute(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            var isSingle = true;
            foreach (var element in source) {
                var result = _func(element);
                if (Next != null)
                {
                    Next.ExecuteAsync(result, _waitHandle);
                    isSingle = false;
                }
                else
                    _result.AddNotify(result);
            }
            if (!isSingle)
                _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            return _result;
        }


        internal void ExecuteAsync(T element, ManualResetEvent resetEvent)
        {
            lock(Sync)
            {
                if(_isBusy)
                {
                    DataQueue.Enqueue(element);
                    return;
                }
                _isBusy = true;

                _func.BeginInvoke(element, CallBack, resetEvent);
            }           
        }

        internal void CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            bool set = false;
            var worker = (Func<T, T>) ((AsyncResult) result).AsyncDelegate;
            var resultElement = worker.EndInvoke(result);
            var resetEvent = result.AsyncState as ManualResetEvent;

            lock(Sync)
            {
                _isBusy = false;
                if(Next != null)
                    Next.ExecuteAsync(resultElement, resetEvent);
                else
                    Start._result.AddNotify(resultElement);

                if(DataQueue.Count > 1)
                {
                    var element = DataQueue.Dequeue();
                    ExecuteAsync(element, resetEvent);
                }
                if(Start._result.Count == Count)
                    set = true;
            }
            if(set)
              resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public static class Pipe
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ForEachPipeline<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params Func<T, T>[] pipes)
        {
            Function<T> start = null, previous = null;
            foreach (var function in pipes.Select(pipe => new Function<T>(pipe){ Count = source.Count()}))
            {
                if (start == null)
                {
                    start = previous = function;
                    start.Start = function;
                    continue;
                }
                function.Start = start;
                previous.Next = function;
                previous = function;
            }
            return start != null ? start.Execute(source) : null;
        }
    }
```

Can you guys please help me to make this thing work? If this design is not good for an actual method pipeline, please feel free to suggest a different one.

**Edit**: I have to stick to .Net 3.5 strictly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't immediately find the problem in your code, but you might be overcomplicating things a bit. This might be a simpler way to do what you want.

```
public static class Pipe 
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> Execute<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> input, params Func<T, T>[] functions)
   {
      // each worker will put its result in this array
      var results = new T[input.Count()];

      // launch workers and return a WaitHandle for each one
      var waitHandles = input.Select(
         (element, index) =>
         {
            var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
               delegate
               {
                  T result = element;
                  foreach (var function in functions)
                  {
                     result = function(result);
                  }
                  results[index] = result;
                  waitHandle.Set();
               });
            return waitHandle;
         });

      // wait for each worker to finish
      foreach (var waitHandle in waitHandles)
      {
          waitHandle.WaitOne();
      }
      return results;
   }
}
```

This does not create a lock for each stage of the pipeline as in your own attempt. I've omitted that because it did not seem useful. However, you could easily add it by wrapping the functions like this:

```
var wrappedFunctions = functions.Select(x => AddStageLock(x));
```

where `AddStageLock` is this:

```
private static Func<T,T> AddStageLock<T>(Func<T,T> function)
{
   object stageLock = new object();
   Func<T, T> wrappedFunction =
      x =>
      {
         lock (stageLock)
         {
            return function(x);
         }
      };
   return wrappedFunction;
}
```

**edit:** The `Execute` implementation will probably be slower than single threaded execution, unless the work to be done for each individual element dwarfs the overhead of creating a wait handle and scheduling a task on the thread pool,  To really benefit from multi-threading you need to limit the overhead; PLINQ in .NET 4 does this by [partitioning the data](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/partitioning-in-plinq/).

Comment: Wim, there seems to be a little problem with your code due to the limitation of the number of waithandles (64). If I use data more than 64 in the enumerable, it is failing; grouping the data with 64 elements is also not helpful at all. Any good workaround can you suggest please? BTW, I can't use PLINQ or TPL, have to stick to .net 3.5 solution.

Comment: @Anindya Chatterjee: I forgot about that limitation of `WaitAll`. I've edited the code to just wait on each waitHandle seperately, which has the same effect.

Comment: But like I said, you should limit the overhead and the number of tasks by partitioning the data. The system can't run that many tasks in parallel anyway! Put all elements of the enumerable in a list, split the list in x chunks, and process the chunks with x tasks. Otherwise the whole thing is probably going to run slower than the single-threaded version. Measure performance to find what works best.

Comment: Can you please clarify more on partitioning the data and run them with x tasks; it seems like I have to use TPL or Rx which I can't. Can you please show some example on how to do it in net 3.5. And +1 for the edit, thanks again.

Comment: @Anindya Chatterjee: if don't feel able to do it yourself, you can use the pre-release version of PLINQ and TPL for .NET 3.5. This was the technology preview which was available before .NET 4 was released. It is still available as part of the Reactive Extensions preview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason for taking pipe-line approach? IMO, launching a separate thread for each input with all functions chained one after another would be simpler to write and faster to execute. For example,

```
function T ExecPipe<T>(IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> pipe, T input)
{
  T value = input;
  foreach(var f in pipe)
  {
    value = f(value);
  }
  return value;
}

var pipe = new List<Func<int, int>>() { Add, Square, Add, Square };
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
foreach(var value in list)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ExecPipe(pipe, (int)o), value);
}
```

Now, coming to your code, I believe for accurate pipeline implementation with M stage, you must have exactly M threads as each stage can execute in parallel - now, some threads may be idle because i/p has not reached them. I am not certain if your code is launching any threads and what will be the count of thread at particular time.

Comment: This is kind of Ok, but how to get the result back from it?

Comment: ExecPipe is going to return the result, so you can store it back in a result list (another list/array/queue) in thread-safe way.

Comment: This code seems to be not working. In `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ExecPipe(pipe, value)); ` the value is always coming as 4. Can you please check again?

Comment: @Anindya, oversight on my part - that happens due to lambda closures. I should have put a disclaimer: I haven't tested the code - its for illustration purpose. Anyway, edited the code that should do the trick (again not tested).

Comment: This doesn't work because `QueueUserWorkItem` does not handle return values. The return type for the delegate is `void`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback.aspx

Comment: @Wim, OP was talking about input value and not about return value!

Comment: @VinayC: I know. I was not commenting on the value always being 4. I was merely pointing out that the computation results don't go anywhere in your example.

Comment: @Wim, value being always 4 is a case of picking only last i/p value (and not result) due to lambda closure. I had already pointed out to OP that if he needs the result then he should store the return value of ExecPipe in result list/array (see earlier comments). Besides, I was just trying to illustrate that chaining functions would be better & simpler way that simulating hardware a like pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you break off a thread for each iteration and aggregate your results in a locking resource. You only need to do. Could use PLinq for this. 
I think you might be mistaking methods for resources. You only need lock a method if it is dealing with a critical block with a shared resource in it. By picking a resource off and breaking into a new thread from there, you eliminate the need to manage your second method.

I.E.: Method X Calls Method1 then Passes value into Method2
Foreach item in arr
Async(MethodX(item));